# Change default error message "This email address is already in use" when registering a new user in WordPress using Caldera Forms

Tags: user-registration

I need to change the default error message "*This email address is already in use*" that WordPress returns when trying to register a user with an email address that already exists.
I am using a **Caldera Form** for the registration process and the **Form Processor** "***User Registration***".
I have added the following piece of code in ***functions.php***

```
add_filter('registration_errors', 'filter_registration_errors');

function filter_registration_errors($error){
   
     if ( $error->get_error_messages('email_exists')) {
       
          $error = new WP_Error('email_exists', 'Your email is already registered. Please, sign in by clicking in the Login link');
     }
     return $error;
}
```

But I am still getting the default message "*This email address is already in use*".

Any clue will be more than appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to enquire in Caldera Form's support channels

Comment: Thanks. But Caldera forms are no longer supported as they have now been discontinued

Comment: If they've discontinued it and it's no longer supported, it'd probably be a good idea to not use it any longer.  Also, if it's not being supported/updated, then I guess it's safe to break the rules and just go edit the file.